# Replace NA's in a column with a date in same column grouped by name

Tags: r, dplyr

Problem: Need to fill out NA's with the non NA value in same column grouped by name.

**Data:**

```
Name   Date
Bob    <NA>
Bob    2015-11-01
Bob    <NA>
Bob    <NA>
Ant    <NA>
Ant    <NA>
Ant    2015-11-03
Ant    <NA>
Ted    2015-11-04
Ted    <NA>
Ted    <NA>
Ted    <NA>
```

**Desired outcome:**

```
Name   Date          Date.Combined  
Bob    <NA>          2015-11-01
Bob    2015-11-01    2015-11-01
Bob    <NA>          2015-11-01
Bob    <NA>          2015-11-01
Ant    <NA>          2015-11-03
Ant    <NA>          2015-11-03
Ant    2015-11-03    2015-11-03
Ant    <NA>          2015-11-03
Ted    2015-11-04    2015-11-04
Ted    <NA>          2015-11-04
Ted    <NA>          2015-11-04
Ted    <NA>          2015-11-04
```

The dates in Date column are not in a fixed position and are randomized,
(Bob[2], Ant[3], Ted[1]). They may appear more than once for the same user, but the date will always be the same for that user.

**My logic:**

Group by name, replace `NA`s in column Date by non `NA`s.

**Attempt 1**

```
df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(Date.Combined = !is.na(Date))
```

then tried

```
df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(Date.Combined = ifelse(is.na(Date), !is.na(Date), !is.na(Date))
```

But these only gave me `TRUE`/`FALSE` instead of the actual dates.

Question1 - How do I find the values of non `NA` values of column instead of getting `TRUE`/`FALSE`.

Question2 - Is `replace` a suitable option over `ifelse`?

Answer (score 1):

The following may not involve your logic but may solve your issue.

Create a vector (subset of the original), wherein you have only the non-NA values. That will be the mapping vector to fill out the NA values.

Say 'data' is your vector. With 'name' and 'date' as your columns, you have NA values in 'date' column.

## Step 1: Create a mapping file

```
>  mapping<-data[!is.na(data$date),]
```

This will have all non-NA rows. If there are more than one non-NA but same values in date, do

```
> mapping<-unique(mapping)
```

(This step with 'unique' function may not be required if there is only one non-NA value corresponding to every 'Name' value)

So the mapping will be something like this.

```
Name   Date
Bob    2015-11-01
Ant    2015-11-03
Ted    2015-11-04
```

## Step 2: Select from the mapping file

To fill out the NA values, map the 'Name' in the mapping vector to know what 'Date' will correspond to them and paste them in the 'Date' column of 'data'.

```
data$Date<-mapping[match(data$Name,mapping$Name),2]
```

Now all the 'NA' will be replaced by what you require.

Comment: I was able to use your method and get what I wanted! Although I needed to change it to 
data$Date<-mapping$Date[match(data$Name,mapping$Name)]

Answer (score -1):

Use *tapply* and named vector:

```
i <- tapply(a$date, a$Name, function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1])
date.combined <- levels(a$date)[i[a$Name]]
```

This assumes *date* is a factor.  This also assumes that the first non-na value for each name is the one you want, like if you only have a single non-na value.